# SQL IN Query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server, but it is taking a long time because of the `IN` clause. How can I optimize this?

```
DECLARE @PriorityIn TABLE ([PriorityId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL);
DECLARE @GatewayId BIGINT = 4;

INSERT INTO @PriorityIn
    SELECT PriorityId 
    FROM PriorityProviders 
    WHERE ProviderId = @GatewayId AND Type = 0

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MessageIn 
WHERE ScheduleDate < GetDate() 
  AND CurrentStatus IN (0, 3, 6) 
  AND ((ProviderId IS NULL 
        AND PriorityId IN (SELECT PriorityId FROM @PriorityIn)) 
       OR ProviderId = @GatewayId);
```

When I look at this query, it runs very quickly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MessageIn 
WHERE ScheduleDate < GetDate() 
  AND CurrentStatus IN (0, 3, 6) 
  AND ((ProviderId IS NULL AND PriorityId IN (1, 2)) 
       OR ProviderId = @GatewayId);
```

This is the execution plan for it:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try making the `PriorityId` the primary key.  This forces an index on the table variable and might change the execution plan.

Comment: Also try to load distinct values from PriorityProviders, probably you load too many repeat values.

Comment: Is there an index in the `PriorityId` column on the `MessageIn` table?

Comment: Yes, index is already there in PriorityId column in MessageIn table. In PriorityProvider table there is only 2 entries. But in MessageIn table there is 8 Million Records

Comment: Why are you doing this (using a table variable to store `PriorityID`s) when the only possible value for `PriorityID` is 4?   This could be an XY problem.

Comment: @TabAlleman 4 is for providerid and i am taking priorityids based on it.

Comment: I see, "providerId" and "priorityId" looked alike when I was quickly scanning.

Answer (score 2):

Table variables almost always perform worse than temp tables because of poor cardinality estimates (no statistics), serialized modifications, etc.There are many blogs on this, [here is one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2825/sql-server-temp-table-vs-table-variable-performance-testing/) and here is [Brent Ozar discussing some differences](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/).

So, change that to a temp table and see if it helps for a start. The more rows that are in `@PriorityIn`, the more likely it is to help.

I'd also change `@GatewayId` to `INT` unless `ProviderId` was also a `BIGINT`. There's no reason for the implicit conversion otherwise. This should apply to `PriorityId` as well.

Also, [here's a good blog post on kitchen sink queries and performance](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) that could speed it up

Comment: when i use temp tables it gives me response in 11 second but in case of table variables it gives me a response in 4 second.

Comment: So it's 4 seconds when you use a table variable, what is it when you use static values? Can you paste the execution plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: When i use static values then it returns result in 0 second. I have added in my question.

Comment: can you paste the execution plan of all three?

Comment: Execution plan is added to the question it self.

Comment: Pictures don't help much since we can't click on them and see what the prdicate, rows, etc are. Can you use that link? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: yes, i have already done that, below is the url : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk02K4L7m

Comment: @mayurRathod i haven't. THe majority of your cost is coming from the count(*) but I don't see why this would be faster when you provide the literal values.

Comment: that is what i am seeing from last 2 days. by the way thanks for the queck answer

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more @mayurRathod

Answer (score 0):

I have just change my query to bellow and now i get quick response, like before it was taken 4 sec and now it take 1 second, both result with 8 Million records in MessageIn table.
But still looking for better result.

```
DECLARE @GatewayId INT = 4;
DECLARE @PriorityIn TABLE(
    [PriorityId] [INT] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @PriorityIn
SELECT PriorityId FROM  PriorityProviders WHERE ProviderId = @GatewayId AND Type = 0


SELECT count(Id) From MessageIn m
LEFT JOIN @PriorityIn o on m.PriorityId = o.PriorityId
WHERE ScheduleDate < GetDate() AND CurrentStatus in (0,3,6) AND 
((ProviderId is null AND o.PriorityId is not null) 
OR ProviderId = @GatewayId)
```